# Equal width flexbox columns in IE

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm building a simple flexbox column layout and have to support IE10. I'm finding that IE will grow a flex child with its contents, while other browsers keep each flexbox at an equal width.

I can solve this issue by setting a `max-width: 50%`, but this means we need percentages based on the number of columns we want. It works for two columns, but for three we'd need `33.333%` etc.

Is there any other way to make IE10/11 to keep flex widths equal?

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <p>hey there this is some long text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>


.columns {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-flow: row;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/gimifixexo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I think `flex-grow: 0` would solve this issue, can't test it right now though. Have you try disabling it with `-ms-flex: 0 0 auto`?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm finding that IE will grow a flex child with its contents, while
>   other browsers keep each flexbox at an equal width.

No, that is not entirely correct, they all, by default, size the flex item based on its content.

There is a difference though, where for most browsers a flex item's default *flex* is `flex: 0 1 auto`, but for IE10 it is `flex: 0 0 auto`.

This basically mean all but IE10 allow flex item's to shrink (the second value represents *flex-shrink*).

So to make this work, all that should be needed is `flex: 1 1 0`.

*But*, to also make IE 10 and 11 behave, we need to give the *flex-basis* a unit, `0px`, and IE10 might also need `width: 100%`, though can say for sure as I run mine emulated.

With the short `flex: 1`, IE11 will, in general, automatically set its *flex-basis* with a unit, though for IE10 it might not, and I'm not fully sure if the prefixed property is *bug free*, and since I can't test it properly not having devices with the older browsers, using the full shorthand `*-flex` will be safer.

Stack snippet

```css
.columns {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /*  "flex-flow: row" is default, and so is "width: 100%"
  -ms-flex-flow: row;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;*/
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0px;                  /*  IE10 fix  */
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 0;                /*  changed  */
  flex: 1;                            /*  changed  */
  min-height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;                        /*  IE10 might need this  */
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <p>hey there this is some long text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <p>hey there this is some long text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <p>hey there this is some long text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish I could give this answer several thousand upvotes. I was pulling my hair out before finding this.

Comment: @WillD Your comment is worth a thousand, so thanks :)

Comment: Nearly three years later this is still relevant for IE11. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So flex right now is a major problem for IE10/11. It has some major problems which have work arounds. I do not have an environment to test but the link below should provide you the resources needed to solve your problem.

http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Pay attention to the Known Issues page, this is just a note. Even though CanIUse does list flex as working for IE11 I can confirm that many of its elements are broken as well.

Also, just so you know, if you want to use columns and have an odd number, like 3. Using 33% will work perfectly fine. On top of this just use

```
justify-content: space-between
```

or alternatively

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

This will make it seems like the columns by evenly distributed by spacing them appropriately. There is more information on justify-content here.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: I understand the limitations of flex in IE, I'm just hoping someone has any other solutions to this problem outside of max-widths. I know that 33% works but it requires that every instance with a different column count has to have a counterpart max-width. I'd prefer to avoid any manual effort to get the sizing right. justify-content doesn't have any impact on width. If you can get it to work, please update the jsbin.